# Python не двигает курсор при помощи window.move(curses)

Tags: python-3.x, curses

Возникла проблема с модулем curses. Есть ли возможность передвигать курсор внутри окна при помощи метода move? А то в моем случае курсор застывает на одном месте. Операционная система MacOS High Sierra
Вот сам код:

```
import curses
from curses import KEY_RIGHT, KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN

def show_menu():
    my_screen.erase()
    key = my_screen.getkey()
    my_screen.addstr(1, 1, "chunk")
    while True:
        cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y = my_screen.getyx()
        if key == KEY_UP:
            cursor_pos_x+=1
        elif key == KEY_DOWN:
            cursor_pos_x-=1
        elif key == KEY_RIGHT:
            cursor_pos_y+=1
        elif key == KEY_LEFT:
            cursor_pos_y-=1
        my_screen.addstr(2, 1, str(cursor_pos_x)+ " " + str(cursor_pos_y))
        my_screen.move(cursor_pos_x,cursor_pos_y)
        my_screen.refresh()
        key = my_screen.getkey()


my_screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.resize_term(40,125)
curses.curs_set(2)
show_menu()
curses.endwin()
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У меня в high sierra iterm2 сработало...

Comment: Получилось двигать курсором свободно?